# jquery click() not consistently called

Tags: jquery, click

I'm going crazy.  I have a series of divs that have click events bound to them.  Most of them work as expected, but a few of them just do nothing.  There is no difference in the code between them (whether in the javascript that produces them or the resulting HTML I see in the element inspector).  They all work in Safari, but in Chrome I get this sometimes-fail.  In the code below, even the "PLAY" is never written to the console.

It's hard to share the code because it's part of such a larger thing, but it basically looks like the following.  First some HTML that gets written into the document from javascript:

```
<div class='thumbnail' id='p-"+ip+"'></div>
```

Which results in something like:

```
<div class='thumbnail' id='p-220'></div>
```

I then bind a click() onto it, like this:

```
      playHandler(ip);

      function playHandler(ip) {
          $("#p-"+ip).click(function() 
            console.log("PLAY");
            popTranscription.listen("canplayall",function() { this.currentTime(ip) });
            popTranscription.play();
            cued = true;
          });
      }
```

Most of the time a click on the div fires the bound function.  Sometimes not.  It's always the same specific thumbnail class divs that don't work (e.g. I have a long list of these in a document, each distinguished by that 'ip' variable.  i.e. ip 1, 2, 3 would always work, while 4 would always not work).

I'm sorry I don't have more to show, but does anyone have any ideas on what to look for?  I'm losing it.  I've tried using bind() instead of click().  I tried onclick instead of jquery, but that gives me strange inconsistent behavior as well (sometimes it finds the function, sometimes not).

UPDATE: the problem was related to duplicate IDs existing on the page.  I added some unique identifiers to the ID strings and the problem cleared up.  thanks for the lead!

Comment: Do you only call `playHandler()` once per `ip`? Or do you call it whenever you want to click the element?

Comment: only once per ip, to bind the click function to that div

Comment: And you're not using `id` over and over, are you? Is this page online?

Comment: not online.  i do resuse ip, it's in a for() which, at its top, declares ip each time with 'var ip = arrayname[i].ip', then eventually feeds it into the code I posted above.

Comment: Are you sure you're producing valid HTML? And Jonathan was asking about having multiple `<div>`s with the same `id` attribute, that's a specific type of invalid HTML that will cause confusing things to happen.

Comment: ah, i see what you're asking.  yes, just looked and that could be an issue.  id p-220 is reused, but only in elements that are never visible at the same time (e.g. the first id='p-220' is in a div that is set to display:none whenever the second id='p-220' is in a div that is showing).  but this is a good lead.  hard to get the HTML out to validate...is there anyway to grab computed HTML from element viewer?

Comment: When is `playHandler(ip)` being called? Is this just an issue of needing to wait for DOMReady?

Comment: it's in a $(document).ready().  i think the problem is indeed with duped IDs.  even though they aren't visible at the same time, they must still be available and thus mucking up the event firing.  i'm rewriting to append some semi-unique IDs to the ID string and will report back.

Comment: Doesn't matter if they're visible or not if they're both in the DOM. Selectors don't ignore things that aren't visible. You cannot have duplicate `id` attributes in one page and expect things to work properly, which one an `id` selector matches is implementation defined.

Comment: mu, if you want to put your comments in an answer i'll accept it...otherwise this one goes officially unanswered

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
 $(".thumbnail").click(function() {
            var idchunk = $(this).attr('id');
            var ip = idchunk.split('-');
            console.log("PLAY");
            popTranscription.listen("canplayall",function() { this.currentTime(ip[1]) });
            popTranscription.play();
            cued = true;
          });
```